# Program keeps printing "keep playing" instead of reading the code

Tags: java, loops

Every time I run my program, if the point limit was not met it is supposed to ask the user to keep playing, and if they choose yes then it is supposed to go back to the loop and run the code again but it is not doing that.  when I enter "yes" it just prints the amount of points i currently have rather than going back to the loop.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Blackjack {

    private int points;
    private int limit;
    private Scanner scan;

    public Blackjack() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    }

    /*Purpose: To print the current points and the limit.
      Input: Points and Limit
      Output: Points and Limit
    */
    public void displayPoints() {
        System.out.println("Your points:" + points + "/" + limit);
    }

    /*Purpose: To ask the user for the game limit.
          Input: Game limit
          Output: Entered limit
        */
    public void startGame() {
        System.out.println("Enter point limit:");
        limit = scan.nextInt();
        displayPoints();
    }

    /*Purpose: To get the roll value from rolling a dice
      Input: Nothing
      Output: Random dice number
    */
    public int getRoll() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int roll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("You rolled:" + roll);
        return roll;
    }

    /*Purpose: To see if the player wants to keep playing the game,
      Input: yes or no
      Output: User's response.
    */
    public boolean askUser(boolean firstTime) {

        if (firstTime == true)
            System.out.println("Start Playing?");

        else {
            System.out.println("Keep playing?");

        }
        scan.next();
        return firstTime;
    }

    /* Purpose: to display the result of points in the game.
        Input: No input.
        Output: amount of points in the game.
    */
    public void displayResult() {
        if (points == limit)
            System.out.println("BlackJack!");
        else if (points > limit)
            System.out.println("Bust!");
        else if (points < limit)
            System.out.println("Stand at " + points + " points!");
    }

    /*Purpose: to play all methods
    Input: none.
    Output: Game results.
    */
    public void play() {
        boolean gameOver = false;
        startGame();
        askUser(true);
        String response = "";
        int roll = getRoll();
        while (response.equals("yes") && gameOver == false)
            getRoll();
        points = points + roll;
        displayPoints();
        if (points >= limit)
            gameOver = true;
        else {
            askUser(false);
        }
        displayResult();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blackjack practice = new Blackjack();
        practice.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Daneil. You can beautify your code in [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get response when user type.

I think you can change your askUser method like below code.

```
  public String askUser(boolean firstTime) {
     if (firstTime == true) 
          System.out.println("Start Playing?");

    else {
           System.out.println("Keep playing?");
    }
    String response = scan.next();
    return response;
}
```

then change play method like :

```
public void play() {

    boolean gameOver = false;
    startGame();
    String response = askUser(true);
    ;
    ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made small changes in your code. Try this:

```
package stack;

import java.util.*;
public class Blackjack{

    private int points;
    private int limit;
    private Scanner scan;
    private boolean firstime = true; //new
    boolean gameOver; //new
    private String answer;//new

    public Blackjack(){
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /*Purpose: To print the current points and the limit.
      Input: Points and Limit
      Output: Points and Limit
    */
    public void displayPoints(){
        System.out.println("Your points:" + points+"/"+limit);
    }

   /*Purpose: To ask the user for the game limit.
      Input: Game limit
     Output: Entered limit
    */
    public void startGame(){//Changes
       if(firstime == true) {
            System.out.println("Start Playing?"); 
            answer = scan.next(); 
       }

       switch(answer) {
       case "yes":
           System.out.println("Enter point limit:");
           limit = scan.nextInt();
           int roll = getRoll();
           points = points + roll;
           displayResult();
           break;
       case "no":
           goodBye();
       } 
   }

   //New method
   public void goodBye() {
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
       scan.close();
   }


   /*Purpose: To get the roll value from rolling a dice
     Input: Nothing
     Output: Random dice number
   */
   public int getRoll(){
       Random r = new Random();
       int roll = r.nextInt(6)+1;
       System.out.println("You rolled:" + roll);

       return roll;
   }   

   /* Purpose: to display the result of points in the game.
      Input: No input.
      Output: amount of points in the game.
   */
   public void displayResult(){//Changes
      if(points == limit) {
          gameOver = true;
          System.out.println("BlackJack!");
          displayPoints();
          System.out.println("Keep playing?");
          answer = scan.next();
      }
      else if (points > limit) {
          gameOver = true;
          System.out.println("Bust!");
          displayPoints();
          System.out.println("Keep playing?");
          answer = scan.next();
      }
      else if (points < limit) {
          gameOver = false;
          System.out.println("Stand at " + points + " points!"); 

      }
   }

   /*Purpose: to play all methods
     Input: none.
     Output: Game results.
   */

   public void play(){//Changes

       startGame();
       ENDWHILE:while(gameOver == true || gameOver == false) {
           if(answer.equals("yes")) {
               firstime = false;
               while(gameOver == true) {
                   points = 0;
                   startGame();
               }
               while(gameOver == false) {           
                   startGame();
               }

           }else {
               break ENDWHILE;
           }
       }

       goodBye();
   }

   public static void main(String [] args){
       Blackjack practice = new Blackjack();
       practice.play();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one is working.. you have made 2 little mistakes i have commented inside the code. need to wrap while loop content inside {}. and user input needs to be return as string in askUser function. the following code is working as you wanted.

```
package javaapplication1;
  import java.util.*;




public class JavaApplication1 {

private int points;
    private int limit;
   private Scanner scan;

    public JavaApplication1(){
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    }

    public void displayPoints(){
        System.out.println("Your points:" + points+"/"+limit);
   }
   /*Purpose: To ask the user for the game limit.
      Input: Game limit
      Output: Entered limit
    */
   public void startGame(){
        System.out.println("Enter point limit:");
        limit = scan.nextInt();
        displayPoints();
   }

   public int getRoll(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int roll = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println("You rolled:" + roll);
       return roll;
    }   

    public String askUser(boolean firstTime){

        if(firstTime == true)
        System.out.println("Start Playing?");

        else {
        System.out.println("Keep playing?");

      }

        return scan.next();
    }

    public void displayResult(){
        if(points == limit)
            System.out.println("BlackJack!");
        else if (points > limit)
            System.out.println("Bust!");
        else if (points < limit)
            System.out.println("Stand at " + points + " points!");  
    }



    public void play(){


        boolean gameOver = false;
        startGame();
        String resUser = askUser(true); // add a variable to catch the input //exp-"yes"
        String response = "";
        int roll = getRoll();

        while(resUser.equals("yes")&& gameOver == false){ // you forget the { and use //the variable to check if it is yess or not 
            getRoll();
            points = points + roll;
            displayPoints();


            if(points >= limit)
            gameOver =true;

            else{

            resUser = askUser(false);//catching the new user input 


            }

        }// you forget the }. if you are not wrapping the loop with {}, it will only //execute one line after the loop 

        displayResult();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
    JavaApplication1 practice = new JavaApplication1();

    practice.play();


    }



}
```